# List of properties of Twin primes Dirichlet series

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, dirichlet-series

In a paper [R. Arenstorf - There are infinitely many prime twins](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405509&ved=2ahUKEwi-6-imzs3lAhVMVH0KHblHA7QQFjALegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw1uQkToHwGda2QWKNyYex8Z&cshid=1572769336445)

he stated the following Dirichlet series :

$$
T(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)\Lambda(n+2)}{n^s}
$$

> Question : What are known  properties ( apart from given in the paper ) of $T(s)$

Also , define

$$ T_1(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^s} $$

Such that 
$$ a_n \leqslant \Lambda(n)\Lambda(n+2) $$ for all $n$

> Then , how to compare properties ( like abscissa of convergence ) of $T(s)$ and $T_1(s)$ ?

Example . Let

$a_n = \sin^2(\frac{(\Gamma(n)π/2)}{n})\sin^2(\frac{(\Gamma(n+2)π/2)}{\Gamma(n+2)})w(n)$

Where , $ w(n) = log(n)log(n+2) $

Also ,

> Can we use Tauberian Theorem on $T_1(s)$ with $a_n$ as given above ?

Comment: Since $\Lambda(n)$ is non-zero at prime-powers as well as primes, $t(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x\Lambda(n)\Lambda(n+2)$ really counts twin prime-powers where $t(x)$ is the inverse transform of $T(s)$ $\left(t(x)=\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i}\int_{c-i\,\infty}^{c+i\,\infty}\frac{T(s)}{s}\,x^s\,ds\right)$. One obvious example of $a_n$ is $a_n=\begin{array}{cc}\{&\begin{array}{cc}1&n\in\mathbb{P}\land n+2\in\mathbb{P}\\0&\text{True}\\ \end{array}\\ \end{array}$ which is associated with the twin prime counting function $\pi_2(x)=\sum\limits_{n\le x}a_n$.

Comment: The function $k_2(x)=\sum\limits_{n=2}^x b_n$ where $b_n=\begin{array}{cc}\{&\begin{array}{cc}1&\nu(n)=1\land\nu(n+2)=1\\0&\text{True}\\ \end{array}\\ \end{array}$ is more closely related to $t(x)$ where $\nu (n)$ is the number of distinct primes in the factorization of $n$. The function $\Pi_2(x)=\sum\limits_{n=2}^x c_n$ where $c_n=\frac{\Lambda(n)\,\Lambda(n+2)}{\log(n)\log(n+2)}$ is even more closely related to $t(x)$ since $t'(x)=\log(n)\log(n+2)\,\Pi_2'(x)$. Note that $c(n)\le b(n)\le\Lambda(n)\Lambda(n+2)$ for all $n>2$.